# using smooth function as coordinate transformation

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-explanation

I am **paraphrasing** from Lee's Smooth Manifolds book:

Let $F$ be a smooth map between an open subset $U\subset \mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Write the coordinates in the domain $U$ as $(x^1, \cdots ,x^m$) and assume $\frac{\partial F^1}{\partial x^1}(a)\neq 0$ for a fixed point $a\in U$. Then we can define new smooth coordinates $(u,v^2, \cdots v^m)$ in some neighborhood $V_a$ of $a$ by $$u=F^1, v^i = x^i \forall i,$$

because the Jacobian of the coordiante transformation is nonsingular at $a$.

**Don't understand:** The last sentence. My thought process is, that at first we have the coordinates $$\varphi:x \mapsto (x^1(x), \cdots , x^m(x)) $$ and instead let's look at the coordinates $$\psi: x \mapsto (F^1(x), x^2(x), \cdots , x^m(x))$$ To show that it is a viable choose of coordinates, we have to show that the coordinate transformation $\varphi \circ \psi ^{-1}, \psi \circ \varphi ^{-1}$ functions are diffeomorphisms locally around $a$. If we calculate the Jacobian of $\psi \circ \varphi ^{-1}$, we get
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial F^1}{\partial x^1}(a) & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\frac{\partial F^1}{\partial x^2}(a) & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
\frac{\partial F^1}{\partial x^m}(a) & 0 & \cdots & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$
which has non-zero determinant, hence it is locally diffeomorphic (continuity of determinant etc.), hence the existence of such a $V_a$.

I am not sure about the second map. because there we'd get something weird like $(F^1)^{-1}$

**Question:** Is this what the author meant? How does the second case go?

Comment: If a map is a diffeomorphism, then by definition (or at worst a one line deduction from the definition, depending on how it’s phrased), its inverse is also a diffeomorphism.

Comment: that's a great point, thank you. How about the rest of the arguments? are they correct?

Comment: yea, you just use the inverse function theorem. Though I think the derivative, based on the usual conventions (and if I remember correctly, Lee uses this convention too), should be the transpose of what you have.